# Dataframe find out duplicate values in column based on other columns, and then add label in to it

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, duplicates, conditional-statements, unique

Given the following data frame:

```
 import pandas as pd
 d=pd.DataFrame({'ID':[1,1,1,1,2,2,2,2],
           'values':['a','b','a','a','a','a','b','b']})
 d
    ID  values
 0   1    a 
 1   1    b 
 2   1    a 
 3   1    a 
 4   2    a 
 5   2    a 
 6   2    b 
 7   2    b
```

The data I want to get is:

```
    ID  values count label(values + ID)
 0   1    a      3     a11 
 1   1    b      1     b11 
 2   1    a      3     a12 
 3   1    a      3     a13 
 4   2    a      2     a21 
 5   2    a      2     a22 
 6   2    b      2     b21  
 7   2    b      2     b22
```

Thank you so much!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!

Comment: how to realize such function? thank you so much!!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems like you need `transform` `count` + `cumcount`

```
d['count']=d.groupby(['ID','values'])['values'].transform('count')
d['label']=d['values']+d.ID.astype(str)+d.groupby(['ID','values']).cumcount().add(1).astype(str)
d
Out[511]: 
   ID values  count label
0   1      a      3   a11
1   1      b      1   b11
2   1      a      3   a12
3   1      a      3   a13
4   2      a      2   a21
5   2      a      2   a22
6   2      b      2   b21
7   2      b      2   b22
```

Answer (score 1):

You want to group by `ID` and `values`. Within each group, you are interested in two things: the number of members in the group (`count`) and the occurrence within the group (`order`):

```
df['order'] = df.groupby(['ID', 'values']).cumcount() + 1
df['count'] = df.groupby(['ID', 'values']).transform('count')
```

You can then concatenate their string values, along with the `values` using `sum`:

```
df['label'] = df[['values', 'ID', 'order']].astype(str).sum(axis=1)
```

Which leads to:

```
   ID values  order  count label
0   1      a      1      3   a11
1   1      b      1      1   b11
2   1      a      2      3   a12
3   1      a      3      3   a13
4   2      a      1      2   a21
5   2      a      2      2   a22
6   2      b      1      2   b21
7   2      b      2      2   b22
```